# Swift Tabbar bottom border color remove

Tags: swift, uikit

that is my code :
this code output  is : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvCg.jpg)
how can i clear / remove bottom side white color? thank you

```
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
        tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
        tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.6
        tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.tabBarBorderColor
        tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.tabBarBackgroundColor

        tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 30
        tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner] 
        tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
    
   
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupVCs()
 UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
  
}
```

i tried shadow clear and start from -3 pixel bottom. these are not worked